# Ionic 3 Directive. Add Custom Property on Div?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, binding, ionic3, directive

I'm trying to bind to a custom div property, data-disqus-identifier

```
<div class="disqus-comment-count" [data-disqus-identifier]="project.route"></div>
```

I've created a directive for this purpose

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[div]',
  exportAs: 'data-disqus-identifier',
})
export class DisqusCountDirective {

  @Input('data-disqus-identifier') identifier: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

and it's correctly imported in app.module.ts but I'm getting the below error...

```
Can't bind to 'data-disqus-identifier' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an [Attribute Directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) here. So your code would be something like:

In your HTML:

```
<div class="disqus-comment-count" disqusCount [data-disqus-identifier]="project.route"></div>
```

In your Typescript (e.g. disqus-count.directive.ts):

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disqusCount]'
})
export class DisqusCountDirective {

  @Input('data-disqus-identifier') identifier: string;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: Well that stopped the errors.  Its now showing as ng-reflect-identifer, I believe for this to work it would need to be data-disqus-identifier

Comment: Just to clean things up, why not remove the `data-` from `data-disqus-identifier` to avoid any potential conflicts with data attributes, and just to separate concerns more generally. If the data attribute is required for some Disqus plugin, can you rather interact with that plugin in the typescript?